# WCF Self host Publish/Subscribe. How to call publish method from host?

Tags: c#, wcf

Hello I have a Publish/Subscribe WCF service which is hosted in my application rather than IIS.

Here are the service interfaces

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMonitorPublishing))]
public interface IMonitorSubscribing
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Subscribe(int processId);

    [OperationContract]
    void UnScubscribe(int processId);

    [OperationContract]
    void PublishWriteConsole(string Name);
}


[ServiceContract]
public interface IMonitorPublishing
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void WriteConsole(string line);
}
```

Here is the Subcription Service

```
public class MonitorSubscriptionService : IMonitorSubscribing
{
    public delegate void WriteConsoleEventHandler(object sender,    ServiceEventArgs e);
    public static event WriteConsoleEventHandler WriteConsoleEvent;

    IMonitorPublishing publishCallback = null;
    WriteConsoleEventHandler WriteConsoleHandler = null;

    public void Subscribe(int processId)
    {
        publishCallback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMonitorPublishing>();
        WriteConsoleHandler = new WriteConsoleEventHandler(PublishWriteConsoleHandler);
        WriteConsoleEvent += WriteConsoleHandler;
        //PublishWriteConsole("Winning")
    }

    public void UnScubscribe(int processId)
    {
        WriteConsoleEvent -= WriteConsoleHandler;
    }

    public void PublishWriteConsole(String text)
    {
        ServiceEventArgs se = new ServiceEventArgs();
        se.Text = text;
        WriteConsoleEvent(this, se);
    }

    public void PublishWriteConsoleHandler(object sernder, ServiceEventArgs se)
    {
        publishCallback.WriteConsole(se.Text);
    }
}
```

The Services host fine and i am able to add the service reference in my client application. if i uncomment the "Winning" line this triggers the client's callback method fine (after some time). This leads me to believe that the subscription and callbacks are working great.

My question is, at various points in the host application i wish to print to subscribed clients console via the PublishWriteConsole callback method. How do i make this function call in the host application Do i need to connect to service my own application is hosting? I'm alot confused any help would be appreciated.

Here is the relevant App.Config bits

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Monitor.MonitorSubscriptionServiceBehaviour"
           name="Monitor.MonitorSubscriptionService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5050/Monitor"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address=""  binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="Monitor.IMonitorSubscribing">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Monitor.MonitorSubscriptionServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"/>      
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```